# BitmapImage from Stream returns 1x1px instead of the whole image

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapsource

I have a method that opens a `FileStream` and creates a `BitmapImage`, by using the `StreamSource` property.

Somehow, in a single machine, trying to open a big image (6000x4000px) results in the method returning a 1x1px image instead.

First I thought that the image was being loaded from a shared folder on the local network, but It was stored in the downloads folder of the same computer.

I saw that the image was "blocked/locked" by Windows because it was downloaded from an unverified source, so I opened Properties and unlocked it. Trying to load the image again resulted in the same problem.

The image was fully downloaded.

### Background information:

The machine with the problem:

- Windows 7 SP1.
- 32 bits.
- Net Framework 4.6.2.
- 4GB of memory, with 2.5GB being used.

My machine (it works as expected):

- Windows 10, build 15063.413.
- 64 bits.
- Net Framework 4.7.
- 8GB of memory, with 6GB being used.

### Code:

```
public static BitmapSource SourceFrom(this string fileSource, int? size = null)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

        if (size.HasValue)
        {
            //It's not possible to get the size of image while opening, so get from another place.
            var refSize = fileSource.ScaledSize(); //Gets the size of the image.

            if (refSize.Height > refSize.Width)
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = size.Value;
            else
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = size.Value;
        }

        bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;               
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        bitmapImage.Freeze(); //Just in case you want to load the image in another thread.
        return bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
var image = "C:\Image.jpg".SourceFrom(); //Without any other parameter.
```

### Question:

- Is there any case that my code is not treating properly, at least that explains why I'm getting a 1x1px image instead of the full size one?
- Also, why it does not throw an `Exception` if it can't load the image?

### Probable answer:

- My code does not handle if the image finished downloading or not, but the image was fully downloaded, so I'm not sure if this is the case. [I've found a similar thread about the same problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8acc67f4-62bb-4a9e-a607-0faed90f333d/bitmapimage-not-loaded-1x1-pixel?forum=wpf).

## Working code:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(fileSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memory);
        memory.Position = 0;
//...
```

Just replace this part of the code and use the `memory` variable instead of `stream` while setting the `StreamSource` object.

Comment: Is that machine (on which you have a problem) 32-bit one?

Comment: @Evk 32 bits, I'll update the post with the information.

Comment: And all other machines on which you do _not_ have this problem with the same file are 64-bit?

Comment: @Evk Yes, and a different OS too. I updated the post.

Comment: On that particular machine, are you sure the download completed? Can you open the file in Windows Photo Viewer?

Comment: Yes, I even copied the image to my computer before trying to load it again.

Comment: So, if you put breakpoint after `EndInit()`, your saying bitmapImage has the height and width properties equal to 1?  Also my research turned up this article: https://dlaa.me/blog/post/6129847

Comment: Yes, the resulting `image` variable has the 1x1 image. I'm not able to debug the app on the machine that returns this faulty image. The article talks about a problem in choosing the right DecodePixel values, I managed to overcome this with my code above, but that's not the problem. :)

Comment: About your last remark, you can check that `IsDownloading` is true to verify this? Though not sure what exactly it can "download" if you are initializing image from local file.

Comment: While the code you're showing should just work, there is perhaps one more thing you could try. Create a MemoryStream and copy the FileStream content to the MemoryStream via its CopyTo method. Then set the MemoryStream's Position to zero and load the BitmapImage from the MemoryStream.

Comment: @Evk Yes, I believe that I can. I'll use an infinite `while` and maybe a Thread.Sleep or a Task.Wait.

Comment: @Clemens Oh sorry, I wanted to reference the other user, typed your nickname instead. I'll try as you wrote, using a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: @Clemens This code was built this way to avoid file usage problems (open and release the file), I remember having issues loading from an `URI`.

Comment: @Clemens Worked, by using a `MemoryStream` and `CopyTo()`. Now, the only problem is to know why exactly this happened... :(

Comment: No idea. According to the documentation it should work without copying to a MemoryStream. I encountered the same problem once when I tried to create a BitmapImage from the stream of a WebResponse. Apparently it couldn't be read in one go, and I had to copy it to a MemoryStream before before decoding a BitmapImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when the image file is very large, or for some other reason the source stream can't be read immediately, you'll have to copy the source stream to an intermediate MemoryStream, and assign that to the `StreamSource` property of the BitmapImage:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;               
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    bitmapImage.Freeze();
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `BitmapImage` creates a default image with 1x1px when decoding of the image fails. You need to register the `DecodeFailed` event to detect this.

```
Exception decodeEx = null;
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = fileStream;
    bitmapImage.DecodeFailed += (_, e) => decodeEx = e.ErrorException;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    if (decodeEx != null)
        throw decodeEx;

    bitmapImage.Freeze();
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

In my case it turned out to be a `OutOfMemoryException`. Indeed decoding only failed when the memory usage was high and the native functionwhich is actually called by `BitmapImage` (using unmanaged memory) was probably unable to allocate enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, the CacheOption is not in the right place on your code!! juste add it befor the endInit();

```
 source.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
```

like this ->

```
                BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
                source.BeginInit();
                source.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                source.StreamSource = fs;                  
                source.EndInit();
```